# Filtering array of object using key in Javascript (node.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, lodash

Please anyone can help, I want to filter data based on key in node.js, I've tried most of things, but didn't worked.
Below example data which needs to be filtered. I could able to filter key:value pair, nested Json object but filtering Array of json object is not working.
E.g. var data =

```
[{
    "createdBy":"Tom"
    "logistics" : 0,
    "paymentStatus" : "Paid",
    "orderAmount" : 5393.75,
    "details" : {
         "street": "S.S road",
         "postCOde": "440111",
    },
    "subOrders" : [
        {
        "name" : "sub Product1",
        "mrp" : 12,
        "details": "desk"
        },
        {
        "name" : "subProduct2",
        "mrp" : 89,
        "details": "chair"
        }
    ]
}]
```

result object should be filtered based on given permission array

```
var permissionArray = ['logistics','paymentStatus','details.street','subOrders.name','subOrders.details'];
```

filtered result should look like

```
{
   result = [{
        "logistics" : 0,
        "paymentStatus" : "Paid",
        "details" : {
             "street": "S.S road",
        },
        "subOrders" : [
            {
               "name" : "sub Product1",
               "details" : "desk"
            },
            {
               "name" : "sub Product1",
               "details" : "chair"
             }
         ]
}]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: `map-obj` and `filter-obj` might be useful, see https://github.com/sindresorhus/filter-obj

edit: also `object-path`, https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a two step approach where you group same keys in an array and store the nested properties as well to the grouped parents.

This is important if you have same parent keys, like

```
['subOrders.name', 'subOrders.mrp']
```

For example a grouped array looks like this:

```
[
    [
        "logistics"
    ],
    [
        "paymentStatus"
    ],
    [
        "details",
        ["street"]
    ],
    [
        "subOrders",
        ["name", "mrp"]
    ]
]
```

Then build new objects based on the key and nested keys.

```js
function filter(keys) {

    var pathes = keys.reduce((r, path) => {
        var [key, ...rest] = path.split('.'),
            temp = r.find(([q]) => q === key);

        if (rest.length)
            if (temp) temp[1].push(rest.join('.'));
            else r.push([key, [rest.join('.')]]);
        else
            if (!temp) r.push([key]);

        return r;
    }, []);

    return function (object) {
        const keys = pathes.filter(([key]) => key in object);
        return Object.fromEntries(keys.map(([key, rest]) => [
            key,
            rest
                ? Array.isArray(object[key])
                    ? object[key].map(filter(rest))
                    : filter(rest)(object[key])
                : object[key]
        ]));
    };
}

var permissionArray = ['foo', 'logistics', 'paymentStatus', 'details.street', 'subOrders.name'],
    data = [{ createdBy: "Tom", logistics: 0, paymentStatus: "Paid", orderAmount: 5393.75, details: { street: "S.S road", postCOde: "440111", }, subOrders: [{ name: "sub Product1", mrp: 12 }, { name: "subProduct2", mrp: 89 }] }],
    result = data.map(filter(permissionArray));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Working great, but if any field is present in permissionArray and not in data then it is making that key with blank value, which is creating issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60645153/9792594 @grodzi's answer below is the most complete and the most general in my opinion. It handles all your edge cases etc. I think.

Comment: @Prakashrathod, it filters now unknown properties as well. please see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @radulle's answer to allow the 'details.name' dot notation desired:

(Also updated to now allow multiple subfields of one field - like 'subOrders.name' and 'subOrders.details')

```js
var arr = 
[{
    "createdBy":"Tom",
    "logistics" : 0,
    "paymentStatus" : "Paid",
    "orderAmount" : 5393.75,
    "details" : {
         "street": "S.S road",
         "postCode": "440111"
    },
    "subOrders" : [
         {
        "name" : "sub Product1",
        "mrp" : 12,
        "details": "desk"
        },
        {
        "name" : "subProduct2",
        "mrp" : 89,
        "details": "chair"
        }
    ]
}]


var permissionArray = ['logistics','paymentStatus','details.street', 'details.postCode','subOrders.name', 'subOrders.details'];

var arrFiltered = arr.map(el => {
  let newEl = {}
  for (let elm of permissionArray){
    if (elm.includes('.')){
    
      //console.log(elm);
      const split_arr = elm.split('.')
      //console.log(el[split_arr[0]]);
      
      if (el[split_arr[0]] instanceof Array){
      
        if (!newEl.hasOwnProperty([split_arr[0]]) ){
          newEl[split_arr[0]] = el[split_arr[0]].map((child,index) => ({[split_arr[1]]: child[split_arr[1]]}) )
          
        } else {
          el[split_arr[0]].forEach((child,index) => {
            //console.log(child[ split_arr[1] ]);            
            newEl[split_arr[0]][index][split_arr[1]] = child[split_arr[1]];
          })
        }
        
      } else{

        if (!newEl.hasOwnProperty([split_arr[0]]) ){
          newEl[split_arr[0]] = {[split_arr[1]]: el[split_arr[0]][split_arr[1]]}
          
        } else {
          newEl[split_arr[0]][split_arr[1]] = el[split_arr[0]][split_arr[1]];
          
        }      
      }
                
    } else {
      newEl[elm] = el[elm];
    }    
  }
  return newEl;
  }
)

console.log(arrFiltered)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

NOTE: you need to check first if a dot is included with `elm.includes('.')`, then you have to split it into its two parts with `elm.split('.')`, then finally you need to check if the value of the key is an array, like 'subOrders' or if it is just an object like 'details' and handle each case with either directly calling the child key, or mapping over the array and calling the child key.

With the permission array as:

```
var permissionArray = ['logistics','paymentStatus','details.street', 'details.postCode','subOrders.name', 'subOrders.details'];
```

The output is:

```
[
  {
    "logistics": 0,
    "paymentStatus": "Paid",
    "details": {
      "street": "S.S road",
      "postCode": "440111"
    },
    "subOrders": [
      {
        "name": "sub Product1",
        "details": "desk"
      },
      {
        "name": "subProduct2",
        "details": "chair"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

NOTE: upon request of the OP, this now also allows you to have two subfields of one field like `'subOrders.name', 'subOrders.details'`

For this `!newEl.hasOwnProperty([split_arr[0]])` is used to check if the property/key doesn't already exist. If it does not, then create it, but if it does, then modify this existing property/key's value/item.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but a small modification. That code isn't handling scenario if we give multiple array parameter in permissionArray. like add ['subOrders.name','subOrders.mrp'] in permission array. It will only filter subOrders.mrp

Comment: You should say that in your question and include an example with that. I didn't know that. I can try to add that by checking if the current key in the arrFiltered is already present.

Comment: Ok now it handles this too :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building a filtered output, we may operate on original obj and remove its props.

The permissions represent a tree (or trie if node is a word (. delimited))

If we further assume that any specified path is accessible in data, then any leaf has for parent an array or object (and so forth).

We then build a tree, and for any node traverse data and remove the keys which are not part of our specification.

```js
const data = {"createdBy":"Tom","logistics":0,"paymentStatus":"Paid","orderAmount":5393.75,"details":{"street":"S.S road","postCOde":"440111"},"subOrders":[{"name":"sub Product1","mrp":12},{"name":"subProduct2","mrp":89}],"a":{"b":[{"c":3,"d":"a"},{"c":4,"e":"f"}]}}
const d = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) // do not mutate original
const v = ['logistics','paymentStatus','details.street','subOrders.name','subOrders.details','a.b.c']
const tree = v.map(x => x.split('.')).reduce((o, p) => {
  p.reduce((c, x) => (c[x] = c[x] || {}), o)
  return o
},{})
function rec (keep, node) {
  if (Object.keys(keep).length === 0) return
  if (Array.isArray(node)) { return node.forEach(rec.bind(0, keep)) }
  for (const k in node) {
    !(k in keep) ? delete node[k] : rec(keep[k], node[k])
  }
}
rec(tree, d)
console.log(JSON.stringify(d,null,2))
```

Comment: This is awesome and should be the accepted answer. Up-voted.

Comment: Whether it gets accepted or not, thx for your feedback @alex L!

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe do it like this:

```js
var arr = 
[{
    "createdBy":"Tom",
    "logistics" : 0,
    "paymentStatus" : "Paid",
    "orderAmount" : 5393.75,
    "details" : {
         "street": "S.S road",
         "postCOde": "440111"
    },
    "subOrders" : [
        {
        "name" : "sub Product1",
        "mrp" : 12
        },
        {
        "name" : "subProduct2",
        "mrp" : 89
        }
    ]
}]


var permissionArray = ['logistics','paymentStatus','details']

var arrFiltered = arr.map(el => {
  let newEl = {}
  for (let elm of permissionArray) newEl[elm] = el[elm]
  return newEl
  }
)

console.log(arrFiltered)
```

Comment: In permissionArray can you add one more filter 'subOrders.name'. Where subOrders is a array of json object

Comment: check out my answer @Prakashrathod, I did just that :) Building on radulle's great answer

Answer (score 0):

In the following solution, we divide the handling of objects and plain arrays.

We build-up a "qualified key" corresponding to the equivalent string in the permissions array, as we recursively descend into an object along its properties.

If we hit a primitive value, then we end the recursion for that property.

A new object `sanitized` is created for each level of the recursion to contain only the permitted properties.

```js
const data = [{ "createdBy": "Tom", "logistics": 0, "paymentStatus": "Paid", "orderAmount": 5393.75, "details": { "street": "S.S road", "postCOde": "440111" }, "subOrders": [{ "name": "sub Product1", "mrp": 12 }, { "name": "subProduct2", "mrp": 89 }] }]

const isPrimitive = (x)=>x === null || typeof x !== "object"

function sanitize(o, permissions, prefix='') {
    if (isPrimitive(o)) return o
    const sanitized = {}
    for (const[k,v] of Object.entries(o)) {
        const qk = `${prefix}${k}`
        if (permissions.some((p)=>p.match(new RegExp(`^${qk}`)))) {
            sanitized[k] = Array.isArray(v) 
                ? sanitizeArray(v, permissions, `${qk}.`) 
                : sanitize(v, permissions, `${qk}.`)
        }
    }
    return sanitized
}

const sanitizeArray = (arr,permissions,prefix='')=>arr.map((el)=>sanitize(el, permissions, prefix))

const permissions = ['logistics', 'paymentStatus', 'details.street', 'subOrders.name']
const sanitized = sanitizeArray(data, permissions)
console.log(sanitized)
```